# How to setTimeStyle AM/PM to lowercase using the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, datetime, formatting

How can I set the AM / PM time style to lowercase? I'm using the following code and according to Apple's documentation this should returned these values as lowercase but it doesn't.

```
[_detailsTimeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am not sure why Apple's examples show the AM / PM in lower case, but it is easy to make the date string lower case:

```
NSDateFormatter *detailsTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[detailsTimeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSLog(@"%@",[[detailsTimeFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] lowercaseString]);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly. It's strange the documentation shows the wrong output. 

I've also discovered in 12hr mode there is a leading zero before the hour, 01:49pm. Annoyingly I haven't figured out how to remove it. It seems to relate to the device system settings because the clock at the top is the same and it's not there on the simulator.

Comment: @Jim it's a little late, but if you were to set a custom date format (it is gently discouraged though), like:

`date.dateFormat = @"h:mm a";`

You'd get the automatic single-or-double digit for the hours.

Comment: This is ancient though do you think there's a way to remove the space between the `h:mm` and the `a` and maintain lowercase am/pm using an `NSDateFormatter`?

Comment: Tom, I couldn't figure that out either so I just did it manually like so:
    `result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" PM" withString:@"pm"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" AM" withString:@"am"];`

Answer (score 170):

You can change the AM and PM symbols on an NSDateFormatter as follows:

```
[dateFormatter setAMSymbol:@"am"];
[dateFormatter setPMSymbol:@"pm"];
```

or in Swift:

```
formatter.amSymbol = "am"
formatter.pmSymbol = "pm"
```

Comment: @arigold - Do you have the code you're having a problem with?

Comment: I deleted the comment - I posted it in my searches before I realized that the font didn't have any lowercase..thanks for checking in, though.

Comment: The selected answer seems better over all than this to let the formatter do what it wants. In Asian languages though "am"/"pm" is understood, a different character might be used. So the other method would let whatever apple wants to put as AM/PM when localizing. So the chosen is a more robust choice, if such thing is implemented now or might be in the future...

Comment: @AndresCanella If it's specifically the AM/PM that needs to be lowercase (as is asked in the question) then, taking your point in to account, a better solution would be request the AM/PM symbol from the date formatter, lowercase it and use that to set the symbols. Using the accepted answer you could lowercase something you didn't intend to.  Of course it completely depends on what the formatter is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5:

You can add handy extension to date formatter:

```
extension DateFormatter { 
    static let myFormattedDate: DateFormatter = {
         let formatter = DateFormatter()
         formatter.dateFormat = "E MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a" //enter any format you like.
         formatter.amSymbol = "am" //By default AM/PM symbols are uppercased
         formatter.pmSymbol = "pm"
         return formatter
    }()
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
DateFormatter.myFormattedDate.string(from: Date()) // Here enter your date and it will return string value formatted to the format you provided with lowercased am/pm symbols.
```

Checkout [NSDateFormatter.com](https://nsdateformatter.com/) to discover the perfect format.